# How to convert subfolder in a directory using ffmpeg in ubuntu

Tags: command-line, video, ffmpeg, batch

I was looking for a code to convert video files in a directory where it has multiple subfolders for each video file. I want to run a batch code so it can convert the video files and save them where the original file was there.

Example:

```
: tree movies/
movies/
├── subfolder1
│   └── movie1.mp4
├── subfolder2
│   └── movie2.mp4
└── subfolder3
    └── movie3.mp4

3 directories, 3 files
```

And so on.

I want the output to be the same as my main structure but in .m3u8 format.

I have used a code where it can convert each movie manually but for some reason, I can use the .m3u8 file or link only in that server I can't make it work all over the internet.

```bsh
for i in *.mp4; do
   ffmpeg -i "$i" -c copy -map 0 -hls_time 3 -hls_list_size 0 -f hls "${i%.*}.hls"
done
```

Comment: What do you expect to do with the files after they are converted?

Answer (score 0):

From Stack Exchange answer https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/227662/how-to-rename-multiple-files-using-find

`for i in $(find . -name '*.mp4'); do command_you_want_to_execute ; done`